# C Space Invaders enemy movement

Tags: c, sdl

I have to write a clone of space invaders game for university in C language using SDL library for graphics.I am very new to C and programming in general so i struggle with it a lot. For now I have one row of enemies and I'm trying to make it move correctly. This are functions for movement of aliens, which check for the collision with right/left wall(which are SDL_Rects near window edges) and if it happens, enemies move one line lower in the opposite direction. The problem is it works okay for all ten enemies except the first one. Each time when collision with left wall occurs the first alien sort of moves away a bit from others instead of moving in one block as I want it to. I noticed that if I change the first for loop in move_aliens function to start from i=11 and i--, the same thing will happen to the enemy in last column. But I still dont know how to fix it.
I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, give me an idea or sollution :). 
I uploaded a video of whats happening http://sendvid.com/dt1reizc

```
void move_down (GameState *game)
{
    int i=0; 
    for(; i < HMALIENS; i++)
        game->alien1[i].y += 25;
}

int collided(int a1, int b1, int a2, int b2, int width1, 
             int height1, int width2, int height2)
 {
     return (!((a1 > (a2+width2)) || (a2 > (a1+width1)) || 
            (b1 > (b2+height2)) || (b2 > (b1+height1))));
 }


void move_aliens(GameState *game)
{
    int i=0;
    for(; i < HMALIENS; i++)
    {
    if (game->alien1[i].dir==LEFT)
       game->alien1[i].x -= 10;
    if (game->alien1[i].dir==RIGHT)
       game->alien1[i].x += 10;

    if (collided(game->alien1[i].x, game->alien1[i].y, 
        game->leftwall.x, game->leftwall.y, 50, 50, 1, 600))
     {
         int i = 0;

         for(; i < HMALIENS; i++)
            game->alien1[i].dir=RIGHT;
         move_down(game);
     }
  }

if(collided(game->alien1[i].x, game->alien1[i].y, game->rightwall.x, 
   game->rightwall.y, 50, 50, 1, 600))
{
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < HMALIENS; i++)
        game->alien1[i].dir=LEFT;

     move_down(game);
 }
}
}
```

//edit
HMALIENS is just a constant (11), the number of living enemies at the start
GameState is a structure.
LEFT/RIGHT stand for direction of movement (quite obvious) [enum Direction {LEFT, RIGHT};]. I have in my alien1 structure enum Direction dir and in the function which load_game function i set it to RIGHT.

```
typedef struct
{
    Player player;
    Rightwall rightwall;
    Leftwall leftwall;
    Alien1 alien1[HMALIENS];
    SDL_Texture *bulet;
    SDL_Texture *ship;
    SDL_Texture *Alien1;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
 } GameState;
```

Comment: Posting definitions of `GameState, HMALIENS, LEFT, RIGHT`, etc. would help in understanding the issue.

Comment: aliens moves in block all to gather in same direction, (odd first then even if you wish, but in same direction), you don't have to set every one's direction. set the direction a global variable

Comment: to make it easy, set a rect that holds all the aliens, then do test collusion with the wall.

Comment: you even don't have to do test collision.  just do `move five steps left then down , five steps right then down, and so ...`, on every down check if any has riched the bottom.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting this right but later on in the game player will be able to shoot at enemies so anytime the rightmost/leftmost enemy would get killed number of steps would change

Comment: @milevyo, in Space Invaders it's possible some of the aliens will be destroyed. If the ones on the edges are gone, it won't be 5 steps any more. Steps could be checked instead of rects, but additional logic is needed to handle missing aliens.

Comment: as i remember, the steps do not change. anyway do what makes your life easier, it doesn't matter if steps change or not, you can update later the game to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
void move_aliens(GameState *game)
{
    int i=0;
    for(; i < HMALIENS; i++)
    {
        if (game->alien1[i].dir==LEFT)
            game->alien1[i].x -= 10;
        if (game->alien1[i].dir==RIGHT)
            game->alien1[i].x += 10;
    }

    if (collided(
        game->alien1[0].x, game->alien1[0].y,
        game->leftwall.x, game->leftwall.y,
        50, 50, 1, 600))
    {
        int i = 0;

        for(; i < HMALIENS; i++)
            game->alien1[i].dir=RIGHT;

         move_down(game);
    }

    if(collided(
        game->alien1[HMALIENS-1].x, game->alien1[HMALIENS-1].y,
        game->rightwall.x, game->rightwall.y,
        50, 50, 1, 600))
    {
        int i = 0;
        for(; i < HMALIENS; i++)
            game->alien1[i].dir=LEFT;

        move_down(game);
    }
}
```

I have tried to make the minimum changes. But @milevyo's more extensive rewrite looks good as well.

The problem, I think (just from looking), is you has the left collision test inside the loop so when that hits, the movement gets out of sync.

Also it was pretty subtle that the right collision test used `i` from the previous loop which happens to index the last element (the rightmost alien). I changed that to explicitly use `HMALIENS - 1`. When you start destroying aliens,
you'll have to track the first (leftmost) and last (rightmost) living aliens and use them for you collision tests.

Your indentation and formatting were a little off which makes the code much harder to read. Formatting is important, and will be even more so when your code gets more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef enum{
    LEFT,
    RIGHT
}GAME_DIRECTION;

int dir=LEFT;

#define SPRITE_WIDTH    50
#define SPRITE_HEIGHT   50
#define BOTTOM_LINE     600


void move_down (GameState *game)
{
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i < HMALIENS; i++)
        game->alien1[i].y += 25;

}

void do_slide(GameState *game)
{
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i < HMALIENS; i++)
        game->alien1[i].x += dir?10:-10;

}


int collided(GameState *game)
 {
    int i;

    for(i=0; i < HMALIENS; i++){
        if(
            game->alien1[i].x <= game->leftwall.x                 || 
            game->alien1[i].x >= game->rightwall.x +SPRITE_WIDTH  || 
            game->alien1[i].y >= BOTTOM_LINE - SPRITE_HEIGHT
        )
        return true;
    } 
    return false;
 }


void move_aliens(GameState *game)
{
    if(collided(game)){
        move_down (game);
        dir=!dir;         // update direction; 
    }else{
        do_slide (game);
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't return true/return false c++?

Comment: @AnielaOprządek, indeed yes, but you can define them; its just for clarity

Comment: @milevyo, this is a nice rewrite, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Without rewriting your code, the problem is that you have already moved the first alien ([0]) left,

```
if (game->alien1[i].dir==LEFT)
       game->alien1[i].x -= 10;
```

and *then* you are doing the collision test and flagging all of them to move right, but the loop continues with [1..10], while [0] has already moved.